# jQuery / JSON multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm currently creating a newsfeed on my website. A PHP script is generating JSON after a SELECT query in my database.
When I print_r() the result of this query, I get the following :

```
Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
                       [nom] => Monsieur 
                       [0] => Monsieur 
                       [prenom] => X 
                       [1] => X 
                       [id_promotion] => 17 
                       [2] => 17 
                       [id_commercant] => 236 
                       [3] => 236
                       [article] => article test
                       [4] => article test 
                       [rubrique] => 4 
                       [5] => 4 
                       [date_debut] => 2015-06-17 
                       [6] => 2015-06-17 
                       [date_fin] => 2015-06-25 
                       [7] => 2015-06-25 
                       [prix_origine] => 25 
                       [8] => 25 
                       [prix_promotion] => 20 
                       [9] => 20
                 )
        [1] => Array ( 
                       [nom] => Monsieur 
                       [0] => Monsieur 
                       [prenom] => X 
                       [1] => X 
                       [id_promotion] => 18 
                       [2] => 18 
                       [id_commercant] => 
                       236 [3] => 236 
                       [article] => article test2 
                       [4] => article test2 
                       [rubrique] => 4 
                       [5] => 4 
                       [date_debut] => 2015-06-18 
                       [6] => 2015-06-18 
                       [date_fin] => 2015-06-23 
                       [7] => 2015-06-23 
                       [prix_origine] => 30 
                       [8] => 30 
                       [prix_promotion] => 10 
                       [9] => 10 
             ) 
);
```

The JSON output is the following :

```
[
{
    "0": "Monsieur",
    "1": "X",
    "2": "17",
    "3": "236",
    "4": "article test",
    "5": "4",
    "6": "2015-06-17",
    "7": "2015-06-25",
    "8": "25",
    "9": "20",
    "nom": "Monsieur",
    "prenom": "X",
    "id_promotion": "17",
    "id_commercant": "236",
    "article": "article test",
    "rubrique": "4",
    "date_debut": "2015-06-17",
    "date_fin": "2015-06-25",
    "prix_origine": "25",
    "prix_promotion": "20"
},
{
    "0": "Monsieur",
    "1": "X",
    "2": "18",
    "3": "236",
    "4": "article test2",
    "5": "4",
    "6": "2015-06-18",
    "7": "2015-06-23",
    "8": "30",
    "9": "10",
    "nom": "Monsieur",
    "prenom": "X",
    "id_promotion": "18",
    "id_commercant": "236",
    "article": "article test2",
    "rubrique": "4",
    "date_debut": "2015-06-18",
    "date_fin": "2015-06-23",
    "prix_origine": "30",
    "prix_promotion": "10"
}
```

]

**MY PROBLEM :**
I'm then trying to get the information I want through this script :

```
 $(document).ready(function (){
$.getJSON("newsfeed.php", function(result){
    $.each(result, function(i, field){
        $("#news").html(field.nom + " " + field.prenom + " vous propose " + field.article + " à " + field.prix_origine + "€ au lieu de " + field.prix_promotion + "€ ");
        console.log(field);
    });
  });
});
```

It results in showing the second array, but I don't know how I can chose the array I want to use.
If someone has any informations in order to help me, I would really appreciate.

Comment: Of course your getting the second array, you're overwriting it because you are looping with `$.each`

Comment: I see where the problem was so. But how can I fix it ?

Comment: Put this in your each: `if(i == 0) { //first array } else { //second array }`

Comment: The problem with your solution is I will only be able to use 2 arrays, or maybe I'm wrong ? What if tomorrow, I decide to add 1, 2 or more news to show,

Comment: Then you need to mention that in your question, have a look at Uchiha's answer.

Comment: With your code you can use `result[i].nom`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using as

```
htmldata = '';
$.each(result, function(key){
        htmldata += result[key].nom + " " + result[key].prenom + " vous propose " + result[key].article + " à " + result[key].prix_origine + "€ au lieu de " + result[key].prix_promotion + "€ ";
});
$("#news").html(htmldata);
```

Comment: Because field contains the object with `nom` etc.

Comment: Check my updated result @Rameleu. Sorry I've been in too much hurry to post it as an answer

Comment: So if I want to show the first array, I have to replace key by an int am I right ?

Comment: Yes you have to replace your `key` by `i` and its going to work for you

Answer (score 0):

`html()` function removes the current contents of the HTML element, and replaces it with the value passed. So effectively, you are rewriting the previous value on every iteration. That is why, you will always get the last value of the array in the output. You may want to use the `append()` function instead if you want to show all values :

```
    $.each(result, function(i, field){
        $("#news").append("<p>"+field.nom + " " + field.prenom + " vous propose " + field.article + " à " + field.prix_origine + "€ au lieu de " + field.prix_promotion + "€ "+"</p>");
        console.log(field);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I knew but I was using `html()` in order to see if the javascript was launched or if there was a problem. Anyway thank you for this answer !